# C# Unity SqlConnection invalid Operation ServerVersion

Tags: c#, sql, mono, ioexception

I'm trying to access a SQL Server database, via IP, with this code:

```
string sqlAsk = "SELECT * " +
        "FROM  'account' " +
        "WHERE Name      =" + accountName + " " + 
        "AND   Password  =" + accountPass + " " + 
        "AND   Validation=  1";

string connectionString = "Data Source=[IP], [PORT]; Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Database=[...]; Trusted_Connection=true";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    command = new SqlCommand(sqlAsk, connection);
    dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        sqlResult = dataReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
    }

    dataReader.Close();
    command.Dispose();
}
```

I expect this to do either give me all values with the specified accountname and password and then the method at the end returns either true, or false (check if the user exists).

But what I get is this:

> IOException: Connection lost
>
> Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsComm.GetPhysicalPacketHeader ()
>   (at connection.Open();)

The Visual Studio Debug (`SqlConnection connection`) shows this:

[image: Error]

And none of the documented ways of setting a `ServerVersion` for the connection string work: Type System Version (on Microsofts .NET doc) leads to "keyword invalid"

Comment: What is the `sqlResult`?? You use it in your code - but you don't show what it's defined as ....

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @marc_s : string sqlResult = "";